# Rsync delta update, skip first N blocks (or %)

Tags: rsync

I have a bunch of very large "almost-append-only" files (meaning that a few bytes at the end are changed every day).

I know of the `-B, --block-size=BLOCKSIZE` to check deltas in blocks.

Is it possible to skip the first N blocks (or start checking from the block at 99%)?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot specify the starting block number, but as per the [original text](https://unix.stackexchange.com/revisions/637402/1) of your question, if you can guarantee the source files will only ever be extended and not overwritten, you can use the `--append` option.

From the documentation (`man rsync`),

> **`--append`** This special copy mode only works to efficiently update files that  are  known  to  be  growing larger  where  any  existing  content on the receiving side is also known to be the same as the content on the sender.  The use of `--append` can be dangerous if you aren't 100% sure  that  all the  files  in the transfer are shared, growing files.  You should thus use filter rules to ensure that you weed out any files that do not fit this criteria.

You must use `rsync` without `--append` if "*a few bytes at the end are changed*". If you're copying across a network (`rsync -a path/to/source remoteHost:path/to/destination`) then you will get a full file read of source and destination each time you run `rsync`, but only a checksum per block, and the blocks that have changed, will actually be transferred across the network. Unfortunately, if you're doing a local copy (`rsync -a path/to/source path/to/destination`) then the entire file will be copied if its size has changed.